# jquery, mysql and unicode problems

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I tried using this thing here - http://w3shaman.com/article/jquery-cool-auto-suggest

Works great for latin words, but when it comes to unicode stuff like šč... and other symbols it crashes.

So I read all comments there and one guy suggested to use utf8_encode($data), so I did.
Now jquery does not give an error, just the thing the output comes out in a weird way

[image http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/5864/ss20120112173801.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/5864/ss20120112173801.png)

As you can see **Šreks 2** turned in to **Å reks 2**

And that is just how it looks in database:
[imag2 http://img860.imageshack.us/img860/6202/ss20120112174124.png](http://img860.imageshack.us/img860/6202/ss20120112174124.png)

But I want it to look normal, like everything else in site does when I do not use utf8_encode(); , so maybe there is a way to decode it before output using jquery or any other suggestions? I think it`s a bit too late to change the database.

Oh right, you can see a live preview of my problem here: http://www.filmas-online.lv/search.php , try entering **Shr**

UPDATE:
OK, I found a way to decode ut8 in javascript decodeURIComponent(escape(escap)) , but it now gives me the same error as it would it there would be no utf8_encode at all, so it`s useless

Comment: You need to escape the unicode characters with the Javascript `\uxxxx` syntax

Comment: Sorry, I`m not too familiar with javascript, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to use JSON and pass the database data through [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the way to the client, as I believe this will sort the encoding for you.

Comment: It is already being passed using json_encode()

Comment: It may not be stored in the database correctly, in that case

Answer (score 0):

Before select SQL or DML use

SET NAMES utf8